# Unity Gradle Build failed while trying to build project as an APK or AppBundle (androidx.work.work-runtime problem)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class androidx.work.ArrayCreatingInputMerger found in modules androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0:) and androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0:)
  Duplicate class androidx.work.BackoffPolicy found in modules androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0:) and androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0:)
  Duplicate class androidx.work.Configuration found in modules androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0:) and androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0:)
  Duplicate class androidx.work.Configuration$Builder found in modules androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0:) and androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0:)
  Duplicate class androidx.work.Configuration$Provider found in modules androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0:) and androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0:)
  Duplicate class androidx.work.Constraints found in modules androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.1.0:) and androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.work.work-runtime-2.7.0:)
.....
```

I know where the error is, but I can't find the files and can't remove them!

I've been looking for solutions, but none have worked so far :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate *jar. Find "androidx.work.work-runtime" in the project window and delete one of them.